# cant find module while loading image from a relative path with require()

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to load image from path given in state of a react component. Using an app created by create-react-app. getting below error :

Cannot find module '../assets/images/img-2.jpg'

Already checked that the image exists on path. Also, this happened only after installing react-router-dom and setting up routes.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Carousel,Image } from 'react-bootstrap';


class JumboBanner extends Component {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this);

    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      direction: null,
      images : [
        {path:'../assets/images/img-1.jpg', body:{title:'This is title',text:'Kutchi Text'}},
        {path:'../assets/images/img-2.jpg', body:{title:'This is title',text:'Kutchi Text'}},

      ]
    };
  }

  handleSelect(selectedIndex, e) {
    this.setState({
      index: selectedIndex,
      direction: e.direction,
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { index, direction,images } = this.state;

    const corouselItems = images.map(img=> (<Carousel.Item>
        <Image className="d-block w-100" src={require(`${img.path}`)}/>
        {/* <img
          className="d-block w-100"
          src={require(`${img.path}`)}
          alt="First slide"
        /> */}


      </Carousel.Item>) );
    return (
      <Carousel
        activeIndex={index}
        direction={direction}
        onSelect={this.handleSelect}>
        {corouselItems}

      </Carousel>
    );
  }
}
export default JumboBanner;
-testapp
|-public
|-src
|--assets
|-|-images
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved. It was because I had an index.js file for each folder inside src folder. Default path resolver of webpack and react-create-app constructs an array relative paths and while doing this, it searches for index.js file in cwd, if it finds one, it maps all relative paths to this directory or its immediate parent. Thus, ../ or ./ would get mapped against path inside current working directory. I moved the assets folder inside cwd and problem was solved. Though this is just a workaround, I believe its a better trade off against wasting time trying to figure out internals of webpack or react-create-app boiler plate code.

Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Use imports for loading images it will be solve your problem.

```
import imgOne from '../assets/images/img-1.jpg'; 

<img src={imgOne}/>
```

Comment: i cant use import. thats the whole problem about. I want to store the path in a database and then render the images dynamically based upon image path retrieved from the database.